# Changing colored icons with jquery

Tags: jquery, colors

in my project I have the possibility to change color scheme of an entire layout by clicking the color-button. There are three types of colors. I have only one problem - the problem with icons. By default they're red and by clicking the specified buttons they should turn the exact color the button is. Of course I can do the whole thing, manually changing every single icon to each color depending on event. But that's a a hell of a code and is absolutely not functional. I see how it should work like this. I have three folders for each color. In each folder there are colored icons wit the same name. So by clicking the color button I only need to change the folder name in my "src". Here are some lines of my code:

```
<div id="color-selector-box">
        <div id="red" class="color-button" color-name="#d94d4b" src="img-v4/dl-button-red.png"></div>
        <div id="green" class="color-button" color-name="#86aa66" src="img-v4/dl-button-green.png"></div>
        <div id="blue" class="color-button" color-name="#4ab1d0" src="img-v4/dl-button-blue.png"></div>
    </div>

$('.bg-color-button').click(function(){
    pickedBackground = $(this).attr('color-background');
    var mildBackground = $(this).attr('mild-color');
    var bgType = $(this).attr('bg');

    $('.termine-box').attr('style', 'background:' + pickedBackground+ '!important');
    $('#mobile-navigation-bar').css('background', pickedBackground);
    $('.strong').css('background', pickedBackground);
    $('.mild').css('background', mildBackground);
    if(bgType == 'light') {
        $('.strong, .mild, .impressum a, #mobile-navigation-bar a, #navigation-bar a, .menu-bar, .termine-inside h1, .date-area').css('color', '#1b1b1b');
    } else {
        $('.strong, .mild, .impressum a, #mobile-navigation-bar a, #navigation-bar a, .menu-bar, .termine-inside h1, .date-area').css('color', '#ffffff');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking something like this. you can replace the newsrc with your new path.

```
$('.color-button').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('src','newsrc')
})
```

Comment: Thanx to your advice and some extra info I've found the solution. I've needed to change not the entire src but the part of it.

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the solution I was looking for. Here is the code I was looking for for someone who is looking for same solution.

```
$('.tab-img img').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this)
            $this.attr('src',$this.attr('src').replace('dark-grey-icons','grey-icons'));
        })
```